# How do I add the curve from GauPro in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

GauPro is an R library for fitting gaussian processes. You can also get it to produce a nuce predicted curve for you.

The documentation for GauPro uses builtin r plotting functions to do plots like this:

```
gp <- GauPro(x,y) ## fit a gaussian process model to x & y

plot(x,y) ## plots the x,y points 
curve(gp$predict(x), add=T, col=2) ## adds the predicted curve from the gaussian process
```

What would be the equivalent using ggplot? I can get the points to show up, but I can't quite figure out how to add the curve.

GauPro documentation I refer to is [here](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/GauPro/vignettes/GauPro.html)

Comment: "I can get the points to show up, but I can't quite figure out how to add the curve." I think you'd have a better [mcve] here then if you could show (1) what you did that was successful in terms of having the points show up and (2) what you tried in terms of adding the curve that failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this by building a little data frame of predictions. Let's start by loading the necessary packages and creating some sample data:

```r
library(GauPro)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(69)

x  <- 1:10
y  <- cumsum(runif(10))
```

Now we can create our model and plot it using the same plotting functions shown in the vignette you linked:

```r
gp <- GauPro(x, y)

plot(x, y)
curve(gp$predict(x), add = TRUE, col = 2)
```

[image]

Now if we want to customize this plot using ggplot, we need a data frame with columns for the x values at which we wish to predict, the y prediction at that point, and a column each for upper and lower 95% confidence intervals. We can obtain the x values like this:

```r
new_x <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = 100)
```

and we can get the three sets of corresponding y values using `predict` like this:

```
predict_df       <- predict(gp, new_x, se.fit = TRUE)
predict_df$x     <- new_x
predict_df$y     <- predict_df$mean
predict_df$lower <- predict_df$y - 1.96 * predict_df$se
predict_df$upper <- predict_df$y + 1.96 * predict_df$se
```

this is now quite straightforward to plot in ggplot with themes customized as you choose:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x, y), aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line(data = predict_df, color = "deepskyblue4", linetype = 2) +
  geom_ribbon(data = predict_df, aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), 
              alpha = 0.2, fill = "deepskyblue4") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!